# Why the almost sure convergence of the SLLN doesn't hold here

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

> Let $X$ be a random variable that takes value $1$ with probability $\frac12$ and value $-1$ with probability $\frac12$. For every $i>1$, define the random variable $X_i=X$ with $\mathbb E\:X_i=0$ for all $i$. Show that,
> for each $n$, $$\mathbb P\left(\frac1nS_n=0\right)=0$$

But isn't the stronger law of large numbers says $$\frac1n S_n\rightarrow0\textrm { a.s.}$$ Then isn't $\mathbb P\left(\frac1nS_n=0\right)=1?$ Why the almost sure convergence of the SLLN doesn't hold here?

Comment: You need independence for the a.s. result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $X_i$ are all equal to $X$, so $S_n = n X$.  This implies $\frac 1n S_n$ is $1$ with probability $\frac 12$ and $-1$ with probability $\frac 12$, in particular $\frac 1n S_n \ne 0$ for all $n$.  The law of large numbers doesn't apply here because the $X_i$ are not independent.

Comment: How to justify that $X_i$ is not independent? Did I need to show $\mathbb E(X_iX_j)\neq \mathbb E(X_i) \mathbb E(X_j)?$ @user2647850. Could you help me with that.

Comment: Yes, showing $\mathbb{E}[X_i X_j] \ne \mathbb{E}[X_i]\mathbb{E}[X_j]$ would be enough to show they are not independent.  Here, though, you could also just say that since they're always equal they aren't independent.  If you wanted to formally show it, you could also use $P(X_i = 1, X_j = -1) = 0 \ne P(X_i = 1)P(X_j = -1)$.

Comment: I am getting a problem distinguishing independence from mutually exclusive which would say $X_i\cap X_j$ is empty, @user2647850. Have they related anyway? I will accept your answer then. Sorry, if I am asking a lame question.

Comment: Mutually exclusive implies not independent, and is sort of as far from independent as you can get.  "Mutually exclusive" generally refers to events rather than random variables, i.e. one would say the events $\{X_i = 1\}$ and $\{X_j = -1\}$ are mutually exclusive because $\{X_i = 1\} \cap \{X_j = -1\} = \emptyset$ rather than saying $X_i$ and $X_j$ are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

For $n$ odd, $P(\frac{S_n}{n}=0)=0$.  For $n$ even,  $P(\frac{S_n}{n}=0)=\frac{n!}{((n/2)!)^2 2^n}\approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi n}}$.  However the density function for large $n$ clusters around $0$  leading to the law of large numbers result.

Comment: Could you illustrate why $\mathbb P(\frac{S_n}{n}=0)=0\textrm{ when n is odd}$ and $\mathbb P(\frac{S_n}{n}=0)=\frac{n!}{((n/2)!)^2 2^n}\approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi n}}\textrm{ when n is even}$? And what did you mean by **the density function for large $n$ clusters around $0?$** @herbsteinberg

Comment: For $n$ odd, the number of plus steps cannot equal the number of minus steps.  For even $n$, just using the binomial distribution to get probability that steps in opposite direction are equal.  For the cluster question, $S_n$ has a binomial distribution.  Divide by $n$ and observe the shape of the curve, squeezed between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: Note that for large $n$ the binomial distribution tends to the normal.  The parameters involved are $E(S_n)=0$ and $\sigma^2(\frac{S_n}{n})=\frac{1}{n}$, which $\to \delta(x)$ as $n\to \infty$ or$\lim\limits _{n\to \infty} P(\frac{S_n}{n}\ne 0)=0$

Comment: Since all steps are either plus or minus, when they are equal, the total is an even number.  I get the impression your math background is extremely weak.  Note that my answer assumed independence of $X_k$.